# How do I debug Ruby scripts using Aptana Studio 3 and rbenv?

Tags: ruby, debugging, aptana, ruby-debug, rbenv

I'm using aptana studio 3 in my mac, osx lion, and I'm using rbenv to install rubies, but when I try to run the debugger in aptana I always got this error:

```
/Users/nebiros/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 4: exec: rbenv: not found
```

I already set some environment variables in the aptana ruby debug configuration window:

```
RBENV_ROOT: /Users/nebiros/.rbenv 
RUBYLIB: /Users/nebiros/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1
```

I'm trying to run this command:

- Program: /Users/nebiros/.rbenv/shims/bundle
- Interpreter Arguments: -d
- Program Arguments: exec rake dreadful_dog:process_content --trace -- -f ./assets/test_ssss_content.zip -d /tmp
- Working Directory: /Users/nebiros/Projects/dreadful_dog

Answer (score 0):

Aptana terminal loads the .aptanarc instead of .bashrc on start up. 
You can adjust the path configurations for rbenv like this

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.aptanarc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.aptanarc
```